# Push down quantifiers and simplification of a FOL formula

Tags: first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I have this formula:

$\forall x,y(R(x,y) \wedge \exists z R(x,z))\qquad(1)$

I remember that it is correct to push down the universal quantifier in this way:

$\forall x(\forall y R(x,y) \wedge \exists z R(x,z))\qquad(2)$

I also think the first conjunct of $(1)$ implies the second one, then $(1)$ can also be semplified in just

$\forall x,y(R(x,y))\qquad(3)$

My problem is that I don't think an analogous implication would hold for $(2)$, then I'm not able to reach $(3)$ passing from $(2)$ (while, if the three formulas are equivalent, it should be possible).

Where am I wrong? I think the error is in the implication leading to $(3)$, but I don't see exactly why.

Comment: (1,2,3) are equivalent to one another, and (2)'s first conjunct does imply its second conjunct.

Comment: @ryang Thank you, even if I asked why.

Comment: No problem, and welcome to this site! If the below answer has resolved the issue, do consider accepting and/or upvoting it.

Answer (score 1):

The Wiki article [prenex normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form) for some more examples of rules for shifting quantifiers around $\land$ and $\lor$ and whether they work when the domain is empty.

$\forall x \mathop. \varphi(x) \land \psi$ is equivalent to $(\forall x \mathop. \varphi(x)) \land \psi$ where $\psi$ does not contain a free occurrence of $x$ holds if we constrain the domain of discourse to be non-empty, but fails otherwise. (For example, consider what happens when $\varphi = \top$ and $\psi = \bot$.)

However, $\forall x y \mathop. R(x, y)$ does imply $\forall x \exists y \mathop. R(x, y)$, always. It holds even if the domain of discourse is empty because it is headed by a universal quantifier.

Additionally, $\forall x \mathop. \varphi(x) \land \psi(x)$ is equivalent to $(\forall x \mathop. \varphi(x)) \land (\forall x \mathop. \psi(x))$ whether empty models are allowed or not.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! W.r.t. your sentence "$\forall xy . R(x,y)$ ... always", I think it doesn't hold if the arguments of R have a different domain and, in particular, if the domains are respectively not empty and empty. Am I right?